# Layout form with CSS so that form is centered but with left aligned variable width fields and right aligned button

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to format a form using CSS. Here is my sample HTML:

```
<div id='login'>
  <h3>Log In</h3>
  <form action='/' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <div class='centerform'>
      <label for='userId'>User Id:</label>
      <input id='userId' maxlength='30' />
      <label for='password'>Password:</label>
      <input id='password' type='password' maxlength='30' />
      <label for='longer'>Longer Field:</label>
      <input id='longer' maxlength='50' width='50' />
      <label for='checkbox'>I have a bike:</label>
      <input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Bike'>
      <input type='submit' class='button' value='Submit' />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want the form to look like this:

[image: Centered form]

Notice that the input fields are left aligned to each other, the labels are right aligned to each other, the submit button is right aligned to the entire form, and the whole thing needs to be centered horizontally in the page. This same CSS needs to work for many different forms with variable width fields.

My current CSS looks like this:

```
.centerform  label{
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   text-align: right;
   /*background-color: green;*/
 }
 .centerform  input{
   font-size: 100%;
   float: right;
   width: 50%;
 }
```

The only thing that gets right is the alignment of the labels. I also am not sure on how to indicate the lengths of the fields. Any width I set in the html gets overridden by the CSS.

I DO NOT want to use any hard coded pixel or percent sizes except for the variable length fields if necessary.

EDIT: I figured out how to have variable length fields by using the size attribute.

Comment: https://designshack.net/articles/10-css-form-examples/

Comment: Thank you for these links. They are helpful. However, those examples all seem to use hard-coded pixel widths. I am trying to avoid hard-coded widths.

Answer (score 0):

This layout might be of help to you. I have given the dimensions in percentage as asked.

```css
.centerform label {
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16%;
}

.centerform input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 82%;
}

.button {
    width: 20% !important;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id='login'>
  <h3>Log In</h3>
  <form action='/' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <div class='centerform'>
      <label for='userId'>User Id:</label>
      <input id='userId' maxlength='30' />
      <label for='password'>Password:</label>
      <input id='password' type='password' maxlength='30' />
      <label for='longer'>Longer Field:</label>
      <input id='longer' maxlength='50' width='50' />
      <label for='checkbox'>I have a bike:</label>
      <input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Bike'>
      <input type='submit' class='button' value='Submit' />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Rather than indicating a hard-coded percent width, can the width be driven by the width of the longest label? Also, I'd like the fields to not be the same width and the checkbox ought to align left as well.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.centerform ul{margin:0;padding:0}
.centerform ul li{list-style:none;padding:5px 0;}
.centerform label{width:18%;display:inline-block;text-align:right;}
.centerform input{display:inline-block;width:80%;text-align:left;}
.centerform input[type='checkbox']{display:inline;width:auto;}
.centerform input[type='submit'] {display:inline;width:auto;float:right;}
```

```html
<div id='login'>
  <h3>Log In</h3>
  <form action='/' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <div class='centerform'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for='userId'>User Id:</label>
          <input maxlength='30' />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for='password'>Password:</label>
          <input type='password' maxlength='30' />

        </li>
        <li>
          <label for='longer'>Longer Field:</label>
          <input maxlength='50' width='50' />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for='checkbox'>I have a bike:</label>
          <input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Bike'>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label></label>
          <input type='submit' class='button' value='Submit' />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are expecting, you can simply adjust `.centerform label` and `.centerform input` `WIDTH` to adjust and fit the form's overall width.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping it would be possible to have the width of all the labels automatically set to the width of the longest one. Same for the fields. That way I don't have to manually enter widths for each form. Seems CSS cannot do this without a table.